# brew services list shows mysql running but cannot connect

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I followed instructions on installing mysql using brew from here
https://gist.github.com/nrollr/3f57fc15ded7dddddcc4e82fe137b58e

brew services list shows below output

```
Name  Status  User         Plist
mysql started <username> /Users/<username>/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

But when I run 'mysql' or 'mysqladmin -u root password '' I get error.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Can anybody tell the issue here.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What is your MySQL version? Recently MySQL v8 was released and it is causing problems.

I suggest to first stop the MySQL service via `brew services stop mysql` and then uninstall MySQL via `brew uninstall mysql`.

Next, please remove its data folder by executing `rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql`.

After that please do `brew upgrade`.

If you want to install MySQL v5.7 just do

`brew install mysql@5.7 && brew link --force mysql@5.7 && brew services start mysql@5.7`

This also works for `mysql@5.6` and `mysql@5.5`.

Comment: Thanks! .. coming here after upgrading to macOS Catalina 10.15.4, Only `brew upgrade` solved it to me, without removing data or reinstalling mysql.

Comment: Thanks, finally found this solution.