# MacOS High Sierra MySQL Error : error while setting value

Tags: mysql, macos

I upgrade OS X to High Sierra.

After upgrade, I found some services does not working correctly, which uses MySQL.

I try to connect by

> mysql -u root -p

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

So I try to restart mysql service by

> brew services start mysql

```
Could not find domain for
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl enable gui/503/homebrew.mxcl.mysql` exited with 112.
```

> mysql.server start

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/mangoui-Mac-mini.local.pid).
```

> /usr/local/var/mysql/mangoui-Mac-mini.local.err

```
2018-07-27T05:32:37.570411Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011071] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: Error while setting value 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' to 'sql_mode'
```

Interesting point is

> sudo brew services start mysql

command works.

So I tried

> sudo mysql -u root -p

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

still get same error.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/51511863/2120073 Please see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51512118/2120073 Cheers.

Comment: @DamianDziaduch I got an error message, `Could not find domain for Error: Failure while executing '/bin/launchctl enable gui/503/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7' exited with 112.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that brew has recently upgraded mysql to 8.0, which causes some things to break due to deprecations (in my case 'sql_mode').

If you want to stay with 8.0, you can have a look at:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html
which will guide you through.

If you (for instance for compatibility reasons) decides to stay with e.g. 5.7 you can do e.g.:

```
> brew services stop mysql
> brew switch mysql 5.7.21
> brew services start mysql
> brew pin mysql # Tell brew to stay on this version
```

To see which version you have installed you can type:

```
> brew list --versions mysql
```

Good luck! Hope this helps :-)